Well-founded trees on $\omega_1^{<\omega}$
As a motivation for this question, first consider the countable ideal $I$ of $\omega_1$, which has the following property.
(*) For every $A \in I$, there exists some $A' \in I$ such that $A \subseteq A'$ and for every $C \in I$ there is a permutation $\pi$ of $\omega_1$ such that $\pi$ point-wise fixes $A$ and $\pi[C] \subseteq A'$.
This is because for every $A \in I$ we can find a disjoint $B \in I$ and then $A' = A \cup B$ will do.
Now let $T$ be the tree on $\omega_1^{<\omega}-\{\emptyset\}$ (ordered by $\subseteq$) and $I$ be the ideal of $T$ generated by the well-founded trees whose first levels are countable. My questions are the following.
(1) Does $I$ have the analogous property of the countable ideal of $\omega_1$? Namely,
(*) For every well-founded tree $t \in I$, there exists some well-founded tree $t' \in I$ such that $t \subseteq t'$ and for every well-founded tree $s \in I$ there is an automorphism $\pi$ of $T$ such that $\pi$ point-wise fixes $t$ and $\pi[s] \subseteq t'$.
(2) Does any sub-ideal of $I$ have this property?
